# Query works on a Table, but doesn't work on a View

Tags: sql, view

I have 2 tables and I made a View Of them

My View Name is ViewMix

this code was for my table

```
var Qsearch = db.tbl_lessons.SqlQuery("select * from tbl_lessons where eTeacher in (" + teacher + ")");
```

that was correct

and now I want to run that query for my View

i wrote :

```
  var Qsearch = db.ViewMix.SqlQuery("select * from ViewMix where eTeacher in (" + teacher + ")");
```

I got an error : "invalid object name 'ViewMix'"

I tried this too :

```
  var Qsearch = db.ViewMix.SqlQuery("select * from dbo.ViewMix where eTeacher in (" + teacher + ")");
```

and got an error too :
"invalid object name 'dbo.ViewMix'"

what is the problem ?

Comment: You view isn't in the default schema (`dbo`?). How did you create it?

Comment: What's the database? SQL Server?